# Is it possible to route to html file via url-hash at nginx?

Tags: nginx

I want make nginx to send different html files to user depends on hash at the url.
I'm trying to do this:

```
location /#water {
    try_files /water.html =404;
}
location /#air {
    try_files /air.html =404;
}
```

but it doen't work. Is it possible? How to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fragment`, that portion of a URL after the `#` is not transmitted to the server, so it cannot be used with location containers.