# # in URL required but doesn't work on PC in Qt app

Tags: qt, nginx, falconframework

I have a Qt app that I have inherited and have to support. There is a piece of code that generates a URL that looks like this:

```
http://foo.bar.com:8000/#/workitem/71327434512586907410/report
```

The page is then loaded with `setUrl`

On a Mac this works fine, but on Windows the page is not loaded, and I do not even see the request reach the server. I found this:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTWEBKIT-56

On the Mac where it works I do not see the # in the request that the server gets. But if I remove the # in the code, I get a 404.

So my questions are this:

1. What does the # mean in this context?
2. Why is it required for this URL to be recognized?
3. Why does it work on Mac and not on Windows? Is it that bug in the link?

The webserver is nginx, and the framework is falcon.

I have a bit more info on this.

When the URL contains the # I see in the nginx log this:

```
POST /workitem/67876029556368716590/report
```

And the request is successfully served.

But when the URL does not have the # I see this in the log:

```
GET /workitem/67876029556368716590
```

And that returns the 404.

Another update:

I have figured out that the # is a Angular JS routing thing:

[AngularJS routing without the hash '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash)

So now my only question is, is there a Qt bug that is preventing this from working in Windows.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655200/is-it-possible-to-route-to-html-file-via-url-hash-at-nginx/33655820#33655820)

Comment: That doesn't tell me why, without the # I get a 404.

Comment: Without the `#` you are sending the URI: `/workitem/71327434512586907410/report` to the server, which presumably does not exist there. With the `#` you are sending the URI: `/` to the server.

Comment: In the server's log, with the #, when I run the Qt app on a Mac I see this `/workitem/71327434512586907410/report` But when I run the app on Windows I do not get anything in the log. If I type the URL into the brower's address bar with the # it also works on a Mac but not on Windows.

Comment: Is it preceded by a `GET /`? Because I would suspect that the client uses the fragment to instigate an AJAX request. But I am just guessing now.

Comment: I just updated the question with a bit more info.

Comment: Updated the question again with more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash

Answer (score 1):

'#' is an unsafe character and should be encoded.

> All unsafe characters must always be encoded within a URL. For
>      example, the character "#" must be encoded within URLs even in
>      systems that do not normally deal with fragment or anchor
>      identifiers, so that if the URL is copied into another system that
>      does use them, it will not be necessary to change the URL encoding.
>   http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

Comment: I tried sending`http://foo.bar.com:8000/%23/workitem/71327434512586907410/report` and I got a 404. I also tried `QUrl::toPercentEncoding` and that encoded the / in addition to the # and it didn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be a big red herring. I was able to modify the system so that I did not need the # in the URL and it still didn't work. Turned out the issue was that the code was trying to download jquery using SSL and it did not work on systems that did not have the SSL libs installed. I changed the code to download jquery from my server instead of the internet and it all worked.